Nuxt3 with Laravel 11 and Sactum Auth CSRF Error
Everything I try is not working with my auth script from Laravel 11 and Nuxt 3.
I installed sanctum and configure the cors config like in every tutorial. But somehow the CSRF token can't be transmitted or something, I don't know. It's also not working in Postman.
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
ROOT_URL=http://localhost:8000
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,127.0.0.1
SESSION_SAME_SITE=none
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false

Laravel 11 AuthController:
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $validatedData['name'],
        'email' => $validatedData['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($validatedData['password']),
    ]);

    $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'token' => $token], 201);
}

bootstrap/app.php:
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;


return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();
        $middleware->append([
            \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            StartSession::class,
            ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Nuxt3 Register Method:
export const register = async (name: string, email: string, password: string, password_confirmation: string): Promise<string> => {

// Step 1: Fetch CSRF token from Laravel
await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/api/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include', // Include credentials to get the CSRF cookie
});

// Step 2: Retrieve the XSRF-TOKEN from cookies
const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

console.log(token);

if (!token.value) {
    throw new Error('CSRF token not found. Make sure cookies are enabled.');
}

// Step 3: Make the registration request
const { data, error } = await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/api/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include', // Include cookies in the request
    body: {
        name,
        email,
        password,
        password_confirmation
    },
    headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token.value as string, // Set the CSRF token in the headers
    },
});

// Handle any errors from the API
if (error.value) {
    throw new Error(error.value.data.message || 'An error occurred during registration');
}

// Return token or some data as per your API response
// @ts-ignore
return data.value.token || 'Registration successful';
};

FIX
I have to change my .env file in laravel:
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
ROOT_URL=http://localhost:8000
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
API_URL=http://localhost:8000
WEB_URL=http://localhost:3000

SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_SAME_SITE=lax
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false


Did you do this step ?: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sanctum#sanctum-middleware

yep, but its always:
"CSRF token mismatch" from Laravel.
